# Spring security configuration error /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml and there's no bean called springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to get my head around Spring Security and I am constantly facing these issues. In the following configuration, I am receiving the error saying it cannot find " /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml". Then when I actually remove "/WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/applicationConfig.xml" from following configuration

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
                /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/configuration.xml
                /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/applicationConfig.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
```

then it gives the error " there's no bean called springSecurityFilterChain". I am confused because the tutorial that I was reading does not mention about declaring the bean "springSecurityFilterChain".

The following is current web.xml structure and after it is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>XXXXX</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
                /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/configuration.xml
                /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/applicationConfig.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>



</web-app>
```

Basically it has no beans configured.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jd="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">


</beans>
```

Thanks in advance,

------------ edited

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/configuration.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
                    /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/applicationConfig.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: which tutorial were you referring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `<context-param>` instead of `<init-param>` and it has to be outside the servlet configuration.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>     
<listener>
    <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
                    /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/configuration.xml
                    /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/applicationConfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
             org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot =D It helped me to solve the issue but declaring Spring dispatcher inside context param caused servlet-mapping to locate springdispatcher.xml in unintended location. Do you have any idea on this? Please check the current implementation from question above. Cheers

Comment: remove that init param section "<init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/ServletDispatcher/configuration.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>"  no need of this